# @fontface only appears on refresh

Tags: css, font-face

I'm building a simple landing page [here](http://www.teddeacey.com/TextDistortionEffects/index2.html). I'm calling a custom font (Harbour) via @fontface but on Chrome, the title first defaults to a basic font. It takes a refresh for the custom font to appear. Anyone know what's happening here?

Answer (score 2):

You are not declaring the font in any of your elements.

in your base.css; you are declaring those fonts at body:

```
 font-family: 'Trash', Futura, 'IBM Plex Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
```

you should put:

```
font-family: 'Harbour';
```

in the element you want it to open

like:

```
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0.67em 0;
    font-family: 'Harbour';
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - that was simpler than I thought.

One last thing if you wouldn't mind helping me out again (if it's an easy fix).

The top left header and the bottom right text look like they should be referencing the same font size. I'm a bit out of my depth, however I think the responsive grid is squashing the top left so it renders smaller. Do you know how to target either of these titles individually in css?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add this css

.custom-font {
    font-size: 30px!important;
}

then


add the class to your elements

Comment: Thankyou very much